# Tried to disable guest account and now Ubuntu isn't working

Tags: boot, command-line, guest-session, display-manager

I'm running Ubuntu as a virtual machine (using vmware), and I attempted to disable the Guest account by typing this into the terminal:

```
 sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Then, I typed this in the file and saved:

```
allow-guest = false
```

After doing this, I restarted my system to make sure it worked, and now I get an error saying that my graphics card cannot be identified, prompting me to use default graphics. When I accept these settings to continue, a terminal just pops up that looks like this:

[image: Terminal Interface Screenshot]

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` didn't exist previously, so now you have an incomplete configuration file.

This is what I suggest:

- Try to open a TTY terminal using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
- Type your username + <kbd>Enter</kbd> + password + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to log in.
- Remove the file with `sudo rm /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
- Reboot: `sudo reboot`

Once logged in normally again, check out [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html#disable) in the official documentation about how to disable the guest session feature.

Comment: @CoolDolphinGuy: Great! Then can you please accept my answer by clicking the grey checkmark to the left, so others see that the problem was solved.